# Ruby Array being passed wrong to the javascript layer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

I have an application, where I have an Array of elements on my controller. I want to pass this Array to a Javascript view, and then convert it to a JSON and parse it.

This is my View:

```
<% content_for :page_meta do %>
    <script>
        const filterItems = "<%= @filter_options %>";
        const productItems = "<%= @mdms_products %>";           
    </script>
```

If I debug @filter_options. I have this on IRB:

```
@filter_options.class # => Array
```

And the value:

```
[{:name=>"Solution Type", :uid=>"application", :component=>"HierarchicalListFilter", :props=>{:rootUrl=>"/insulation/commercial/enclosure/applications", :rootText=>"Enclosure Solutions"}, :values=>[{:name=>"Walls", :slug=>"walls", :children=>[{:name=>"Framed", :slug=>"framed", :children=>[{:name=>"Steel Stud", :slug=>"steel-stud"}, {:name=>"Wood Stud", :slug=>"wood-stud"}]}, {:name=>"Masonry", :slug=>"masonry", :children=>[{:name=>"Concrete Masonry Unit", :slug=>"concrete-masonry-unit"}]}, {:name=>"Concrete", :slug=>"concrete", :children=>[{:name=>"Precast", :slug=>"precast"}, {:name=>"Tilt-up", :slug=>"tilt-up"}, {:name=>"Cast-in-place", :slug=>"cast-in-place"}]}, {:name=>"Metal Building", :slug=>"metal-building"},
```

Everything looks perfect right? But, on my javascript console debug, when I get the value of productItems I get this weird String:

```
[{:name=&gt;&quot;Solution Type&quot;, :uid=&gt;&quot;application&quot;, :component=&gt;&quot;HierarchicalListFilter&quot;, :props=&gt;{:rootUrl=&gt;&quot;/insulation/commercial/enclosure/applications&quot;, :rootText=&gt;&quot;Enclosure Solutions&quot;}, :values=&gt;[{:name=&gt;&quot;Walls&quot;, :slug=&gt;&quot;walls&quot;, :children=&gt;[{:name=&gt;&quot;Framed&quot;, :slug=&gt;&quot;framed&quot;, :children=&gt;[{:name=&gt;&quot;Steel Stud&quot;, :slug=&gt;&quot;steel-stud&quot;},
```

And of course, when I try to do a JSON.parse(filterItems) it shows a parse error.

So, Whats is the better way to pass an Ruby Array, to a Json in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a completely different notation than JavaScript, so you must express it in the proper form and ensure that it doesn't get HTML-escaped:

```
<script>
  const filterItems = <%= @filter_options.to_json.html_safe %>;
  const productItems = <%= @mdms_products.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

It may be easier to render out the whole thing as JSON and load it in via AJAX as well.

Comment: Thank you @tadman. On this specific case (i have a BIGGGGG amount of data on my session that i dont need to do async calls to server) it was only a Parsing problem. 

It worked as a charm. Thanks again